# Get list of groups that the user id belongs to in DocuSign REST API

Tags: docusignapi

Is there any REST Api call for getting the list of group name based on user id or user email_id in which group they belongs to?

Answer (score 1):

```
GET https://{{server}}.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{{accountId}}/users/{{userId}}?additional_info=true
```

This call will pull out all the user details. In the body response the node "groupList" will contains the the user belongs.

Sample Reponse:

```
{    
  "userName": "sample string 1",
  "userId": "sample string 2",
  "userType": "sample string 3",
  "isAdmin": "sample string 4",
  "userStatus": "sample string 5",
  "uri": "sample string 6",
  "email": "sample string 7",
  "password": "sample string 8",
  "title": "sample string 9",
  "createdDateTime": "sample string 10",
  "firstName": "sample string 11",
  "middleName": "sample string 12",
  "lastName": "sample string 13",
  "suffixName": "sample string 14",
  "userSettings": [
    {
      "name": "sample string 1",
      "value": "sample string 2",
      "errorDetails": {
        "errorCode": "sample string 1",
        "message": "sample string 2"
      }
    }
  ],
  "sendActivationOnInvalidLogin": "sample string 15",
  "activationAccessCode": "sample string 16",
  "enableConnectForUser": "sample string 17",
  "forgottenPasswordInfo": {
    "forgottenPasswordQuestion1": "sample string 1",
    "forgottenPasswordAnswer1": "sample string 2",
    "forgottenPasswordQuestion2": "sample string 3",
    "forgottenPasswordAnswer2": "sample string 4",
    "forgottenPasswordQuestion3": "sample string 5",
    "forgottenPasswordAnswer3": "sample string 6",
    "forgottenPasswordQuestion4": "sample string 7",
    "forgottenPasswordAnswer4": "sample string 8"
  },
  "groupList": [
    {
      "groupId": "sample string 1",
      "groupName": "sample string 2",
      "permissionProfileId": "sample string 3",
      "groupType": "sample string 4",
      "users": [
        {
          "userName": "sample string 1",
          "email": "sample string 2",
          "userId": "sample string 3",
          "userType": "sample string 4",
          "userStatus": "sample string 5",
          "uri": "sample string 6",
          "errorDetails": {
            "errorCode": "SUCCESS",
            "message": ""
          }
        }
      ],
      "errorDetails": {
        "errorCode": "SUCCESS",
        "message": ""
      }
    }
  ],
  "workAddress": {
    "address1": "sample string 1",
    "address2": "sample string 2",
    "city": "sample string 3",
    "stateOrProvince": "sample string 4",
    "postalCode": "sample string 5",
    "phone": "sample string 6",
    "fax": "sample string 7",
    "country": "sample string 8"
  },
  "homeAddress": {},
  "loginStatus": "sample string 18",
  "passwordExpiration": "sample string 19",
  "lastLogin": "sample string 20",
  "errorDetails": {
    "errorCode": "SUCCESS",
    "message": ""
  },
  "customSettings": [
    {}
  ],
  "profileImageUri": "sample string 21",
  "userProfileLastModifiedDate": "sample string 22",
  "signatureImageUri": "sample string 23",
  "initialsImageUri": "sample string 24"
}
```

more info: https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20User%20Information.htm

Comment: you could explain in brief what the call is doing, links can very easily go dead.